# Gradient not displaying correctly?

Tags: html, css, gradient

i am using this in my body code

```
body { 
  margin:50px;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #2a6da9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1D1D1D, #1F1F1F);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1D1D1D), to(#1F1F1F));   
    }
```

in the background, the gradient displays in blocks that look rough and pixelated. How do i fix this to where it is smooth. I also have tried making an image the background, but had no luck. Thanks

Comment: Try using a tool to generate the gradient css. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.  If that doesn't help please provide a demo or link to your project.

Comment: Please provide a working demo, for instance on http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is browser dependent and I do not see it on mine with the same css. You could try changing it to:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1d1d1d 0%, #1f1f1f 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1d1d1d), color-stop(100%,#1f1f1f));
```

But it is such a slight change in color, I even set the height to over 300px.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 1 X 100 pixel image made the quality look much better